# *file* variable not working

Tags: clojure

I'm reading [in the API docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2afile%2a) that the `*file*` variable should have a value of "the path of the file being evaluated, as a String".  However, this feature seems broken in certain cases.

When I execute a file using `lein exec`, things work as expected:

```
$ cat test.clj
(println *file*)
$ lein exec test.clj 
/path/to/test.clj
```

Yet when I run a test that contains a call to `(println *file*)`, `NO_SOURCE_PATH` is printed instead of the file containing that line.

Why am I seeing this behavior, and how can I reliably access the path and filename of the file being evaluated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`*file*` is set to the path of the file being **compiled**, so after your whole program is compiled it is no longer useful to look at the value of `*file*` (assuming no use of eval).

In your `test.clj` example, the `println` is executed while the file is still being compiled.  If the reference to `*file*` is moved into a test or function, it will only be dereferenced at runtime after the value of `*file*` is no longer useful.

One option is to write a macro that stores the value of `*file*` when it is expanded, so that the result can be used later.  For example, a file `example.clj` could have:

```
(defmacro source-file []
  *file*)

(defn foo [x]
  (println "Foo was defined in" (source-file) "and called with" x))
```

Then from the REPL or anywhere, `(foo 42)` would print:

```
Foo was defined in /home/chouser/example.clj and called with 42
```

Note that it doesn't matter which file `source-file` is defined in, only where it was expanded, that is the file where `foo` is defined.  This works because it's when `foo` is compiled that `source-file` is run, and the return value of `source-file` which is just a string is then included in the compiled version of `foo`.  The string is then of course available every time `foo` executes.

If this behaviour is surprising, it may help to consider what would have to happen in order for `*file*` to have a useful value inside every function at runtime.  Its value would have to change for every function call and return, a substantial runtime overhead for a rarely-used feature.